# New row is not adding in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

My app Add item (i.e Name,age and person image) to List view. But whenever i click on add, it replaces the old listView and no new row is added.
**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private Uri uri;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menuItem)
    {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add to List.");
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        builder.setView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if(uri != null) {

                    EditText nameText = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.name);
                    EditText ageText = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.age);
                    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), nameText.getText().toString(), ageText.getText().toString(), uri);
                    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });

        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void imagePicker(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    i.setType("image/*");
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        uri = data.getData();

    }
}}
```

All i need is this, when i press Add it should add new row in listView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should implement is **notifyDataSetChanged** The same can be done as follow : 
 Create a custom POJO, UserInfo

```
public Class UserInfo{
private String name;
private String age;
private Uri uri;

public UserInfo(String name, String age, Uri uri) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.uri = uri;
}
```

}

- Declare a list of UserInfo

  `private  List<UserInfo> userList= new ArrayList<>();`
- Add following lines in onCreate method.

  `customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userList);
  listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);`
- Change onCLickMethod of dialog by following :

`

```
if(uri!=null){
EditText nameText = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText ageText = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.age);
userList.add(new 
  UserInfo(nameText.getText().toString(),ageText.getText().toString(),uri));
customAdapter.swapData(userList);
}
```

`

- Modify your CustomAdapter

  `List<UserInfo> userList;`

  `public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<UserInfo> userList){
      this.context = context;
      this.userList = userList;
      this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }`

  ```
  `@Override
  public int getCount() {
    if(userList!=null){
       return userList.size();
    }else{
      return 1;
    }
  }
  ```

  `public void swapData(List<UserInfo> userList) {
         this.userList = userList;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
   }`

Hope this helps, Revert if any problem.

Comment: If it worked, can you please upvote my answer. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add [notifyDataSetChange](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

> If, during the course of your application's life, you change the underlying data that is read by your adapter, you should call notifyDataSetChanged(). This will notify the attached view that the data has been changed and it should refresh itself.